# db.insert() returning -1 in android, although I feel the could is written correctly

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I've looked at countless tutorials and previously asked questions, and I feel my code should work. Whenever I go to insert , however, db.insert returns the error code of -1.

Database contract

```
public final class DatabaseContract {


private static final String TEXT_TYPE          = " TEXT not null";
private static final String TEXT_TYPE_NULL     = "TEXT";
private static final String INT_TYPE           = "INTEGER not null";
private static final String INT_TYPE_NULL           = "INTEGER";
private static final String COMMA_SEP          = ",";

// To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
// give it an empty constructor.
private DatabaseContract() {}

public static abstract class Client implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME       = "client";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL1 = "fullname";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL2 = "phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL3 = "photo";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL1 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL2 + INT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL3 + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}

public static abstract class Drink implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME       = "drink";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL1 = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL2 = "desc";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL3 = "upc";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_COL4 = "price";


    public static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL1 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL2 + TEXT_TYPE_NULL + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL3 + INT_TYPE_NULL + COMMA_SEP +
            COLUMN_NAME_COL4 + INT_TYPE +" )";
    public static final String DELETE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
}
```

}

DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final  int    DATABASE_VERSION   = 1;
public static final  String DATABASE_NAME      = "drinkpos.db";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.Client.CREATE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(DatabaseContract.Drink.CREATE_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

mainActivity

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseContract.Drink.COLUMN_NAME_COL1, "fanta");
    values.put(DatabaseContract.Drink.COLUMN_NAME_COL2, "orange");
    values.put(DatabaseContract.Drink.COLUMN_NAME_COL3, "100141166");
    values.put(DatabaseContract.Drink.COLUMN_NAME_COL4, "100");
    // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
    long newRowId;
    newRowId = db.insert(
            DatabaseContract.Drink.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            values);
```

I've tried removing any unnecessary code.
I tried reading from the database anyways after running the above code, and it tells me there's no such third colum (i.e. desc in the case of drinks or photo in the case of theclient table).

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Declare below 2 static variables in DatabaseContract class - public static final  int    DATABASE_VERSION   = 1;
public static final  String DATABASE_NAME      = "drinkpos.db";   and then  increase db version to 2 and recreate the created table in onUpgrade method.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String TEXT_TYPE          = " TEXT not null";
private static final String TEXT_TYPE_NULL     = "TEXT";
private static final String INT_TYPE           = "INTEGER not null";
private static final String INT_TYPE_NULL           = "INTEGER";
```

You're missing spaces in front of `TEXT_TYPE_NULL`, `INT_TYPE` and `INT_TYPE_NULL`. The columns you declare like

```
COLUMN_NAME_COL2 + INT_TYPE
```

get the column name and type concatenated together like `descINTEGER not null` and of course there won't be a column `desc`.

After fixing the problem, you can uninstall your app to recreate the database.